# Decrement function by linking a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Image for what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bDoV.png)

I have H2 = 9-1 = 8. Then I want the next cell to represent the value of 7 so on and so forth(subtracting 1 quantity everytime) based on location/tail number and PN

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to follow your question. Perhaps a screen shot and some actual data would help. Also, explain what you have tried yourself. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also share the version of Excel you have. I think this may be solvable including `SEQUENCE()` which is added since Office 365

Comment: No I am not trying to generate a random sequence of numbers

Comment: Image is up. So basically I would simply like 8 to decrement by 1 (based) on quantity keeping in view the tail and location

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly this van be used in `H2` and filled down:

`=G2-SUMIFS($D$2:$D2,$A$2:$A2,A2,$B$2:$B2,B2,$C$2:$C2,C2,$E$2:$E2,E2)`

It'll substract the cumulative sum of qty for parts having the same conditions.

[image]

Comment: Hey man, appreciate your response but unfortunately, it isn't working perfectly at my end.

Comment: But is the logic usable? (Note the $ in the range to lock the column/row numbers)

Comment: Yeh I noticed that and been experimenting around with your logic. Basically, it works absolutely fine but disregards the conditions where ever they may be in the sheet. So if I go top to bottom, it works perfectly but ignores all the conditions.

Comment: Maybe your screenshot doesn't provide the overview of data to be able to reproduce the answer you're looking for. This answer works on the given info.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I will try to edit the function and see how I can fit the need